# Given URL is not allowed by the application configuration codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I know there a lot of these topics but I still haven't figured out where my problem is. 
So, I'm trying to make a website with the Facebook login option.

The page is located at firechrome(dot)mt(dot)ut(dot)ee
But when clicking the "Click here to login" I get the error:

> "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I made the settings following this tutorial: http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2012/04/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-with-codeigniter-2-1/

Here are my fb settings: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiloA.png

If needed, I can provide the code aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the **App Domains** from the Application Settings

---

**Edit**

On login, I can see that the **AppID** in the login url is **incorrect**. That means you have not change the AppId/Secret in the code- please check.

Another thing I found in the tutorial you mentioned-

> If you are using the files of the example, in the Facebook.php library is in the constructure setting a appId and the secret with others, you just have to delete or comment this lines (line 42 and 43)
>
> ” // $config['appId'] = ’416398375038503′;
>   
> // $config['secret'] = ‘f707a5d557ddb60205a5b8f535e56bac’;
>   ”
>
> in the constructure function of the Facebook.php library to make the api use the yours.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it didn't solve the problem. :/

Comment: You sure, you have given correct AppId and the AppSecret in the code?